# Размещение html кода внутри страниц сайта и безопасность

Tags: javascript, безопасность

Есть сайт, на котором могут размещаться различные новости/посты пользователями. Есть несколько различных типов постов - картинка + текст/просто текст/... 
Хочется расширить возможности пользователей и дать большую свободу - возможность свободного размещения своего HTML кода в новостях. Новости этого типа обязательно проходят премодерацию перед попаданием в основные разделы.

С реализацией проблем нет, всё работает. 
Вопрос по поводу безопасности. Использование `<script>` и любого кода внутри не запрещалось, т.к. опять же, есть премодерация.

**Но, всё же, какие возможности JS стоит точно запретить при таком подходе?**

Из того, что мне приходит в голову: ajax, alert, write, post, get, XMLHttpRequest, XMLHttpRequest, XMLHttpRequest, console.

Под запретом я понимаю вырезание этих названий из кода при создании поста, с помощью базовых функций замены PHP.

Запрещать полностью JS не хотелось бы, т.к. это убивает возможность создания собственных опросов и т.д.

**UPD**

***Спасибо всем за ответы. Обдумал всё и решил отказаться от идеи со свободной вставкой HTML. Дам пользователям возможность использовать markdown разметку.***

Comment: хитрый пользователь всегда может записать script через 's' + 'crip' + 't' и долго будете вырезать.

правильный подход - оставить только список разрешенного, а ещё лучше - использоваться markdown.

Comment: Не проще ли сделать штатную голосовалку? Будь я зловредом, я бы написал красивую голосовалку с длиннющим кодом, который модератор не осилит проверять. И всего пара строк там будет отвечать за мои зловредные мысли.

Comment: @ReinRaus, Ваш хитрющий план достаточно обрушить - просто запретить длинные/зашифрованные/странно_пахнущие/вирусные скрипты :)

Comment: Ах да: нужно очень хорошо разбираться в JS, ибо придёт гуру и накатает скрипт, который непонятно что делает и нельзя понять - резать его или оставить. Вырезать безобидный - это как-то жестоко, юзеры ещё обидятся и уйдут.
А если допускать примитив, типа только алерты всякие - тогда создавай список не запрещённых, а разрешённых конструктов.

Comment: @TheDoctor, еще легче обрушить все планы запретив html. Есть куча решений: bbcode, markdown. Городить костыли- лишняя трата времени.

Comment: @ReinRaus, Мы не ищем лёгких путей! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript - весьма богатый и очень гибкий язык, всех опасных конструкций всё равно не вырежешь, охотники за XSS просто невероятные трюки делают, `'<s' + 'crip' + 't>'` даже рядом не валялось.
Давать встраивать JS, доступный всем - это как-то... не кошерно.
Лучше введи только разрешённые возможности, а остальное режь автоматом.
Но ещё лучше - вообще не разрешать встраивать код. Нужен пользовательский опрос - дай ему форму и на её основе создай сам, т.е. своим скриптом.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше весь js запретить. Да и с html'ом надо очень осторожным быть. И с css'ом.

Дыры обычно не из-за какого-то одного места получаются. А то будет как со скайпом:
- При регистрации не проверяем почту?
- Ну и ладно.
- При сбросе пароля ссылка приходит во все аккаунты?
- Удобно же.
- Регистрируем второй аккаунт на чужую почту и сбрасываем пароль от первого.
- Упс...